# Python-Data from different files (of different lengths) involved in calculations

Tags: python, file, astronomy

I am trying to figure out how to make my code read through each line in the `Members.dat` table, read the `ras` and `decs` in it, look for an `ra` and `dec` match (not exact, but within a certain range since they are from two different surveys) in the other table (Aligned...), and if it finds one to do the calculations using the appropriate `redshift` and `rbandmag` for the `ra` and `dec` match.

If it doesnt find a match, the 'Aligned...' file doesn't have data for every `ra` and `dec` in the `Members.dat` file, then just go to the next `ra` and `dec` pair in `Members.dat` and search for that one.

Right now the code reads though the `Members.dat` table and will return all the `redshifts` and `rbandmags`, but then for the second print statement it only uses the very last pair it reads for all the calculations with the data from the other file (Aligned....).

@mdurant

## !/usr/bin/python

import csv
import numpy as np

if **name** == "**main**":

```
fout = open('newfile.txt', 'w')
group, rab, decb, Redshift, a, b, c, d, e = np.loadtxt('Members.dat', unpack=True)
matched_id, fuv_mag, fuv_flux, nuv_mag, nuv_flux, e_bv, g, raa, deca = np.loadtxt('Aligned FULL MEMBERS WITH DATA', unpack=True)
dist = np.subtract.outer(rab,raa)**2*np.cos(decb)**2 + np.subtract.outer(decb-deca)**2
match_bool = dist.min(axis=0)
best_match = dist.argmin(axis=0)

a = fuv_mag
b = nuv_mag 
v = c*Redshift
MFuv = a-5*(np.log(10*v/70))
MNuv = b-5*(np.log(10*v/70))
Ls=3.846*10**26
LFuv=(Ls)*(np.e**((MFuv-4.47)/-2.5)) 
LNuv=(Ls)*(np.e**((MNuv-4.47)/-2.5))
X = MNuv-Rbandmag
MFuv = a-5*(np.log(10*v/70))
MNuv = b-5*(np.log(10*v/70))
Ls=3.846*10**26
LFuv=(Ls)*(np.e**((MFuv-4.47)/-2.5)) 
LNuv=(Ls)*(np.e**((MNuv-4.47)/-2.5))
X = MNuv-Rbandmag
print >> fout, '{:.2e},'.format(float(LFuv)), '{:.2e},'.format(float(LNuv)), '%f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f' % (Fuvmag, Nuvmag, MFuv, MNuv, g, X,Redshift, Rbandmag)
             
       
        
          
fout.close()
```

So there are two objectives:

1. Find a match within a certain range
2. Do calculations for only the `ras` and `decs` with matches and only with the corresponding data.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

import csv
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    

    fout = open('LGroupall', 'w')


    for line in open('Members.dat'):
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            cols = line.split()  
            Redshift = float(cols[3])
            Rbandmag = float(cols[4])
            c = 2.9979*10**5
            v = c*Redshift
            print >> fout,'%f, %f' % (Redshift, Rbandmag)
    for line2 in open('Aligned FULL MEMBERS WITH DATA'):
            if not line2.startswith('#'):
                cols2 = line2.split()
                Fuvmag = float(cols2[1])
                Nuvmag = float(cols2[3])
                g = float(cols2[6])
                a = Fuvmag
                b = Nuvmag
                MFuv = a-5*(np.log(10*v/70))
                MNuv = b-5*(np.log(10*v/70))
                Ls=3.846*10**26
                LFuv=(Ls)*(np.e**((MFuv-4.47)/-2.5)) 
                LNuv=(Ls)*(np.e**((MNuv-4.47)/-2.5))
                X = MNuv-Rbandmag
                print >> fout, '{:.2e},'.format(float(LFuv)), '{:.2e},'.format(float(LNuv)), '%f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f' % (Fuvmag, Nuvmag, MFuv, MNuv, g, X, Redshift, Rbandmag)
              
    fout.close()
```

`Members.dat` sample:

```
# Group rab decb Redshift a b c d e
2293 215.197952 4.370193 0.02667 -18.116 0.739 0 0.950 1.71
2293 215.186829 4.257247 0.02722 -18.379 0.660 0 0.950 1.59
2293 215.390656 4.447858 0.02743 -17.853 0.523 0 0.943 1.95
2293 215.540527 4.521144 0.02672 -19.289 0.925 0 0.943 1.87
2293 215.647522 4.547533 0.02639 -18.097 0.715 0 0.943 1.76
2293 215.861160 4.533366 0.02646 -17.987 0.330 0 0.943 1.73 
2293 215.711914 4.665845 0.02584 -18.848 0.574 0 0.943 1.56
2293 216.152466 4.559171 0.02598 -20.265 0.666 0 0.987 1.64
2293 216.167786 4.570475 0.02643 -18.496 0.513 0 0.987 1.66
2293 216.474045 4.642701 0.02615 -20.271 0.770 0 0.987 1.61
2293 216.262772 4.364132 0.02686 -18.347 0.491 0 0.987 1.97
2296 220.980103 4.096979 0.02549 -17.933 0.611 0 0.974 2.79
2296 220.881287 4.309001 0.02549 -17.989 0.373 0 0.974 3.08
2296  221.061447   4.218551  0.02557  -20.525  0.939  0  0.974    2.93
2320  216.793182   4.757412  0.02698  -18.566  0.564  0  0.987    1.69
2320  216.884888   4.821614  0.02685  -20.531  0.849  0  0.987    1.68
2320  216.873398   4.779740  0.02753  -20.111  0.699  0  0.987    1.76
2320  216.691772   4.575934  0.02806  -19.103  0.833  0  0.987    1.92
```

`Aligned....` sample:

```
#matched_id fuv_mag fuv_flux nuv_mag nuv_flux e_bv g raa deca 
6383546990167328408     22.11728    5.165242    20.81406    17.15441    0.02696899  2293    215.197952  4.370193  
2429377676145856182 22.33954    4.209049    20.93236    15.38349    0.02696899  2293    215.197952  4.370193
2429377676144817309 21.39752    10.02288    -999        -999        0.02578526  2293    215.186829  4.257247
6383546999829960446 22.0422     5.535058    -999        -999        0.02578526  2293    215.186829  4.257247
6383546990167328949 19.40973    62.53322    19.39661    63.29321    0.02752976  2293    215.390656  4.447858
2429377676145857353 19.61978    51.53339    19.34272    66.51405    0.02752976  2293    215.390656  4.447858
6383546990165232142 -999        -999        19.93376    38.59196    0.03139252  2293    215.540527  4.521144
2429377676145858738 20.62856    20.35057    19.28588    70.089      0.03139252  2293    215.540527  4.521144
2429553598006301900 20.53106    22.2628     20.17618    30.86948    0.02996568  2293    215.647522  4.547533
6383546989093587265 20.6668     19.64633    20.26241    28.51261    0.02996568  2293    215.647522  4.547533
6383546989093587234 18.51288    142.8394    18.3558     165.0736    0.03155341  2293    215.86116   4.533366
2429553598006303442 18.64594    126.3644    18.3048     173.0134    0.02757647  2293    215.711914  4.665845
6383546989093587956 18.84079    105.6055    18.36372    163.875     0.02757647  2293    215.711914  4.665845
2429553598006302429 17.40474    396.3743    17.00334    573.674     0.03030299  2293    216.152466  4.559171
6383546989093587283 17.45678    377.825     17.03622    556.5612    0.03030299  2293    216.152466  4.559171
6383546989093587400 19.14371    79.89501    18.63046    128.1783    0.03030299  2293    216.167786  4.570475
2429553598006302434 19.07138    85.39802    18.62435    128.9025    0.03030299  2293    216.167786  4.570475
6383546989093587315 18.24552    182.7237    17.59955    331.2669    0.03227024  2293    216.474045  4.642701
2429518413634214656 18.04468    219.8524    17.5183     357.0097    0.03227024  2293    216.474045  4.642701
6383546988019847429 18.03906    220.9926    17.47195    372.5806    0.03227024  2293    216.474045  4.642701
2429553598006303494 18.05234    218.3062    17.59173    333.6613    0.03227024  2293    216.474045  4.642701
2937827037201564330 18.11119    206.7875    17.5436     348.7877    0.03227024  2293    216.474045  4.642701
6383546989093586253 19.34859    66.15564    18.8084     108.8025    0.03201414  2293    216.262772  4.364132
2429553598006299849 19.16085    78.64319    18.7739     112.315     0.03201414  2293    216.262772  4.364132
6383546994462298969 19.61141    51.93227    19.43124    61.30603    0.03103101  2296    220.980103  4.096979
2429905441727194814 19.99832    36.36427    19.34747    66.22339    0.03103101  2296    220.980103  4.096979
6383546983724877047 18.67604    122.9098    18.44853    151.5609    0.03023296  2296    220.881287  4.309001
2430010994843455574 18.65218    125.6409    18.40909    157.1673    0.03023296  2296    220.881287  4.309001
2937827037201564850 19.31565    68.19363    18.83648    106.0248    0.03118853  2320    216.793182  4.757412
2937827037199466565 -999        -999        19.97776    37.05916    0.02839247  2320    216.691772  4.575934
6383546988019846679 21.08108    13.41437    20.09341    33.31459    0.02839247  2320    216.691772  4.575934
2429518413634213555 20.98475    14.65897    20.00091    36.27739    0.02839247  2320    216.691772  4.575934
6383546988019848025 22.73846    2.914851    20.76309    17.97894    0.03277461  2320    217.289642  4.769514
```

`LGroupall` sample:

```
0.037170, -18.947000
0.030550, -19.078000
0.030620, -17.943000
0.030760, -20.465000
0.029680, -19.325000
0.029900, -18.618000
0.030040, -19.208000
0.030470, -19.630000
0.030550, -18.344000
0.030420, -18.616000
0.030700, -19.695000
0.030610, -21.650000
0.030460, -18.813000
5.63e+29, 9.48e+29, 22.117280, 20.814060, -13.750652, -15.053872, 2293.000000, 3.759128, 0.030460, -18.813000
5.15e+29, 9.04e+29, 22.339540, 20.932360, -13.528392, -14.935572, 2293.000000, 3.877428, 0.030460, -18.813000
7.50e+29, 1.37e+207, 21.397520, -999.000000, -14.470412, -1034.867932, 2293.000000, -1016.054932, 0.030460, -18.813000
5.80e+29, 1.37e+207, 22.042200, -999.000000, -13.825732, -1034.867932, 2293.000000, -1016.054932, 0.030460, -18.813000
1.66e+30, 1.67e+30, 19.409730, 19.396610, -16.458202, -16.471322, 2293.000000, 2.341678, 0.030460, -18.813000
1.53e+30, 1.71e+30, 19.619780, 19.342720, -16.248152, -16.525212, 2293.000000, 2.287788, 0.030460, -18.813000
1.37e+207, 1.35e+30, -999.000000, 19.933760, -1034.867932, -15.934172, 2293.000000, 2.878828, 0.030460, -18.813000
1.02e+30, 1.75e+30, 20.628560, 19.285880, -15.239372, -16.582052, 2293.000000, 2.230948, 0.030460, -18.813000
1.06e+30, 1.22e+30, 20.531060, 20.176180, -15.336872, -15.691752, 2293.000000, 3.121248, 0.030460, -18.813000
1.01e+30, 1.18e+30, 20.666800, 20.262410, -15.201132, -15.605522, 2293.000000, 3.207478, 0.030460, -18.813000
2.38e+30, 2.53e+30, 18.512880, 18.355800, -17.355052, -17.512132, 2293.000000, 1.300868, 0.030460, -18.813000
2.26e+30, 2.59e+30, 18.645940, 18.304800, -17.221992, -17.563132, 2293.000000, 1.249868, 0.030460, -18.813000
2.09e+30, 2.53e+30, 18.840790, 18.363720, -17.027142, -17.504212, 2293.000000, 1.308788, 0.030460, -18.813000
3.71e+30, 4.35e+30, 17.404740, 17.003340, -18.463192, -18.864592, 2293.000000, -0.051592, 0.030460, -18.813000
3.63e+30, 4.29e+30, 17.456780, 17.036220, -18.411152, -18.831712, 2293.000000, -0.018712, 0.030460, -18.813000
```

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is your question? Seems a similar task to my CMD/photometry module https://github.com/martindurant/astrobits/blob/master/CMD.py

Comment: @mdurant My Question is how to alter my existing code so that it is reading through both the Members.dat and Aligned... files and doing calculations based only with corresponding data (when the ra and dec are nearly the same). The files Im extracting data from both contain data on 4000 some galaxies and right now it is doing the calculations for all the galaxies with just the last Redshift and Rbandmag it reads, instead of using the respective Redshift and Rbandmag for each galaxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you not loop through your files as you are doing. Although this will work, it makes the code hard to read and correct, and can lead to the sort of problem you are having. Instead, you can load the whole file into arrays, and then work on these:

```
group, rab, decb, Redshift, a, b, c, d, e = np.loadtxt('Members.dat', unpack=True)
matched_id, fuv_mag, fuv_flux, nuv_mag, nuv_flux, e_bv, g, raa, deca = np.loadtxt('Aligned FULL MEMBERS WITH DATA', unpack=True)
```

and then you have a match when (rab-raa)**2*cos(decb)**2 + (decb-deca)**2 < limit**2 (I am assuming your units here, please check).

You can either loop through one coordinate set:

```
for i in range(len(rab)):
   dist = (rab[i]-raa)**2*cos(decb[i])**2 + (decb[i]-deca)**2)
   if dist.min()<limit**2:
       print raa[dist.argmin()],deca[dist.argmin()]
```

or form a (big) matrix of distances

```
dist = np.subtract.outer(rab,raa)**2*cos(decb[:,None])**2 + np.subtract.outer(decb,deca)**2
match_bool = dist.min(axis=0)
best_match = dist.argmin(axis=0)
```

Comment: So you are suggesting this instead of my "for line in open..." statements? How would you suggest coding for the finding of raa & rab and deca & decb matches between files?

Comment: This isn't going to work because the Members.dat file is  4852 lines long and the Aligned FULL MEMBERS WITH DATA file is 4621 lines long, therefore I get a ValueError. I dont want the code to do the calculations line by line (data from line 1 in one file used with data from line 1 in the other file, and so on) because the lines won't match up. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: The fact that they are different lengths isn't the reason for the ValueError?

Comment: Okay so the first part opens the file and reads the columns and then one of the two options will find the match. I'm running this code now (see next the code I added to the question) and it is giving me a "ValueError: operands could not be broascast together with shapes (4852, 4621) (48,52)" and referring to line 13 in the code which begins with "dist =". I understand what you are getting at, I'm just trying to figure out why it isn't working, The value error seems to be referring to the different file lengths?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo. I ran the code again and looking over it, it is still giving the ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4621)(4852)

Comment: I tried with empty arrays of my own with the same size as yours and it works... Perhaps you can break the line into multiple stages to see where it's going wrong?

Comment: Yeah I don't know why it isnt working. Traceback says the line that does the calculation for MFuv was called last, and the only thing I can think of that would throw it off is that there are more 'v' values than 'a' values. BUT if is is only doing calculations for ras and decs for which is finds matches, than it shouldnt be an issue

Comment: Ag, but you haven't selected yet! match_bool is the smallest distance, so match_bool<limit**2 gives you the condition, and raa[match_bool<limit**2] the set of R.A.s that have matches, whereas best_match gives the indices of the closest match, such that rab[best_match] is the corresponding R.A.s for each raa and rab[best_match[match_bool<limit**2]] only for those with good matches. Forgive me if raa and rab are the wrong way around. I hope this if enough information.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done with some clever use of numpy.loadtxt and recarrays (see numpy reference for these as well as the documentation on array indexing)

```
import numpy as np

colnames = tuple('Group rab decb Redshift a b c d e'.split())
coltypes = tuple(['i4'] + ['f4']*(len(colnames)-1))
Members = np.loadtxt('Members.dat', dtype={'formats':coltypes, 'names':colnames})

colnames = tuple('matched_id fuv_mag fuv_flux nuv_mag nuv_flux e_bv g raa deca'.split())
coltypes = tuple(['i4'] + ['f4']*5 + ['i4'] + ['f4']*2)
Aligned = np.loadtxt('Aligned.dat', dtype={'formats':coltypes, 'names':colnames})

Members['Group'] == Aligned['g']

for Group in set(Members['Group']):             # [1]

    # get indexes in Members and Aligned for    # [2]
    # this group index
    Midx = (Group == Members['Group'])
    Aidx = (Group == Aligned['g'])

    raa = Aligned['raa'][Aidx]                  # [3]
    deca = Aligned['deca'][Aidx]
    rab = Members['rab'][Midx]                  # [4]
    decb = Members['decb'][Midx]

    # print out the first two element of the data
    # for each group ID
    print 'Group:',Group
    print '    raa = ',raa[:2],'...'
    print '    rab = ',rab[:2],'...'
    print '    deca = ',deca[:2],'...'
    print '    decb = ',decb[:2],'...'

    # do some math with the values:
    print raa * rab
```

Notes:
[1] Looping over all unique Group values
[2] Midx is the "index mask" of this group for the Members data
    and Aidx is the mask of this group for the Aligned data
[3] at this point raa is an array of all the raa values for this
    particular Group
[4] similarly, rab is an array of all the rab values for this Group

I prefer to use column types this way to force index columns to integer types so that masks are more robust. With this, you can go ahead and do the math you want on the group-level. See the output of the last line of the script above.

Comment: Okay so this is just explicitly defining the columns using arrays? Which part of it is looking for matches raa & rab and deca & decb with in a range? Would I leave the rest of my code the same and just insert this before i do the calculations? Will using these arrays make it iterate and use all the redshifts and rbandmags, instead of just the final one it reads?